# Multiplying sparse matrices in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a very large sparse 2D matrix (200k x 100k) (sparsity around 0.002), which I would need to multiply with itself (after transposition).

**A = 200k x 100k**
and I need to calculate:
**A x A.transpose()**

The problem is, that in Tensorflow it seems there is no sparse matrix to sparse matrix multiplication.
`tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul()` requires one side to be turned into a dense matrix, which would hit the memory limit.
`tf.sparse_matmul()` seems to actually require dense matrices.

There is no way to fit the whole matrix (A) in the GPU memory as a dense vector.

Is there a way to multiple sparse matrices with other sparse matrices in Tensorflow? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: sparse_sparse matmul isn't supported as of october 2017

Comment: Thanks, yes, I got to the same conclusion too.